# map sdk for ios which can display only one country

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Is it possible to display map of only one country (for example map of only
Peru ) on a MapView in IOS .I don't want to display the entire world map.I have done enough POC on the concept and reached a conclusion that its not possible on google maps IOS SDK .

Below are the links i refered and felt are relevant but didnt give the result what i wanted

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#overview

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221584/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-single-country-in-google-map-it-should-be-only-one

Is there any map SDK's available for achieving this in IOS or any other mobile platforms ?

Comment: Here is a solution I found in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221584/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-single-country-in-google-map-it-should-be-only-one). Here is the [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/gvvy5vxz/2/)

Comment: I have already viewed the thread , this first link i gave redirects to the thread gien by you,thanks for looking up