# Google Map- How to display only one country in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, angular

I have requirement to display only one country in google map either i can pass the country code and country should appear on the google map if you have any solution please revert below find the code which i was trying to do same?

I have highlighted this part using a below code
I saw many solution but they did it by hiding google properties and set image for the particular country but i want to show the labels as well

```
map_options = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.098116, 96.033701),
                    zoom: 6,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    navigationControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    minZoom: 6, maxZoom: 15,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    //0.2
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                    }

google_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);
        var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'geometry',
                from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
                where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('MM')"
            },
            styles: [
                    {
                        polygonOptions: {
                         //   fillColor: "#87ceeb",
                            strokeColor: "#rrggbb",
                            strokeWeight: "int"
                        },
                        polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: "#rrggbb",
                            strokeWeight: "int"  }
                    },   
            ],
            map: google_map,
            suppressInfoWindows: true
        });[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I want to show only Myanmar country in the google map but the output display other countries as well if you have solution please revert thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display a single country in Google map? It should be only one country, not parts from other countries included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221584/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-single-country-in-google-map-it-should-be-only-one)